# fetch data from website using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

input link for ex is "http://www.unionstationdc.com".I need to programmatically go here "http://www.unionstationdc.com/contact" & fetch contents of this page. I have written this code below but of no use.

```
doc = hw.Load(link);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    bool hreflink = link.GetAttributeValue("p", true);
    if (hreflink == true)
    {
        attr = link.Attributes;
        att = attr.AttributesWithName("p");
        for (int i = 0; i < attr.Count; i++)
        {
            name = attr[i].Name;
            value = attr[i].Value;
            string trim = value.Trim('/');
            string uppercase = trim.ToUpper();
            if (uppercase.Contains("CONTACT"))
            {
                string path = attr[i].XPath;
                MessageBox.Show(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to finish .... Thanks in advance

Comment: just fetch the url you want

Comment: Just create a new `HtmlDocument` from the link you've fetched dynamically : `var newDoc = hw.Load("your_dynamically_fetched_link_here");`

Comment: HI, I am able to get xpath=/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/p[1]/a[4]/@href[1] and outerhtml= <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a> from the above code.Still unable to create a new htmldocument.